# hybris 6.7 mysql 8.0.11 BadSqlGrammarException

Tags: mysql, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to initialize hybris v6.7 with mysql v8.0.11 and driver "mysql-connector-java-8.0.11"
I've created scheme "y" utf8 - utf8_bin and configured it through local.properties

**local.properties**

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/y?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.username=root
db.password=hell0w0rld!
db.tableprefix=
db.customsessionsql=SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
mysql.optional.tabledefs=CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
mysql.tabletype=InnoDB
```

**$ ant clean all initialize**

```
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] ###############################################################
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] Initialize system ...
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] ###############################################################
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] Please wait. This step can take some minutes to complete.
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] If you do not receive any feedback on this page in this time, consult the applicationserver logs for possible errors.
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] Dropping old and creating new empty system ...
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] ### Starting type system initialization
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] >>> Creating schema and type system ...
     [java] INFO  [main] [HybrisSchemaGenerator] Reading type system Information.
     [java] INFO  [main] [HybrisSchemaGenerator] Read type system Information. Time taken 2.335 s
     [java] INFO  [main] [HybrisSchemaGenerator] Preparing  Db model.
     [java] INFO  [main] [DatabaseModelGenerator] Prepared Database Model with (1588) tables.
     [java] INFO  [main] [HybrisSchemaGenerator] Prepared  Db model. Time taken 11.53 s
     [java] INFO  [main] [HybrisSchemaGenerator] Preparing  Statements
     [java] INFO  [main] [HybrisSchemaGenerator] Prepared  Statements. Time taken 4.756 s
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultDbScriptsExecutor] ###### Executing DDL Drop Statements in batch mode ##########
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultDbScriptsExecutor] Executed 880 Statements. Time taken: 1.145 s
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultDbScriptsExecutor] ###### Executing DDL Statements in batch mode ###############
     [java] Sat Jul 14 19:31:45 EET 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultDbScriptsExecutor] Executed 2680 Statements. Time taken: 33.69 s
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultDbScriptsExecutor] ###### Executing DML Statements in batch mode ###############
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultDbScriptsExecutor] Executed 33034 Statements. Time taken: 2.273 min
     [java] INFO  [main] [HybrisSchemaGenerator] DDL DROP Script generated to: /Users/aghoneim/Workspace/Hybris/y/hybris/temp/hybris/init_master_drop_schema.sql
     [java] INFO  [main] [HybrisSchemaGenerator] DDL CREATE Script generated to: /Users/aghoneim/Workspace/Hybris/y/hybris/temp/hybris/init_master_schema.sql
     [java] INFO  [main] [HybrisSchemaGenerator] DML Script generated to: /Users/aghoneim/Workspace/Hybris/y/hybris/temp/hybris/init_master_data.sql
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] >>> Reloading persistence ...
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] >>> Clearing cache ...
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] >>> Initializing media storages ...
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] ### Done type system initialization in 0d 00h:03m:22s:651ms.
     [java] INFO  [main] [Initialization] Restarting system internals ....
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultTaskService] Task engine already stopped.
     [java] ERROR [main] [AbstractAntPerformable] Error occurred while performing ant task
     [java]  org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: ConnectionCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING TABLE_TYPE IN ('TABLE',null,null,null,null) ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_SC' at line 1
     [java]     at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
     [java]     at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:360) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.ddl.tools.persistenceinfo.PersistenceInformation.getAllTableNamesFromDatabase(PersistenceInformation.java:289) ~[ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.ddl.tools.persistenceinfo.PersistenceInformation.allTables(PersistenceInformation.java:276) ~[ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.ddl.tools.persistenceinfo.PersistenceInformation.containsTypeSystemPropsTable(PersistenceInformation.java:95) ~[ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.ddl.tools.MigrateTypeSystemProps.containsTypeSystemPropsTable(MigrateTypeSystemProps.java:72) ~[ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.ddl.tools.MigrateTypeSystemProps.getStatementsToExecute(MigrateTypeSystemProps.java:50) ~[ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.ddl.tools.TypeSystemHelper.assureTypeSystemStructureIsUpToDate(TypeSystemHelper.java:123) ~[ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.assureTypeSystemStructureIsUpToDate(AbstractTenant.java:830) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:737) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:685) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroyAndForceStartupTenant(Registry.java:274) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroyAndForceStartup(Registry.java:263) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization$SessionRecoveryAfterRegistryStartupAwareExecutor.doAfter(Initialization.java:681) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization$SessionRecoveryAfterRegistryStartupAwareExecutor.execute(Initialization.java:691) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization.doInitializeImpl(Initialization.java:565) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization.access$5(Initialization.java:487) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization$5.call(Initialization.java:804) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization$5.call(Initialization.java:1) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.system.InitializationLockHandler.performLocked(InitializationLockHandler.java:80) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Initialization.doInitialize(Initialization.java:836) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.InitPlatformAntPerformableImpl.performImpl(InitPlatformAntPerformableImpl.java:106) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.AbstractAntPerformable.doPerform(AbstractAntPerformable.java:92) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
     [java]     at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Reflect.java:134) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Reflect.java:80) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:858) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(BSHBlock.java:130) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:80) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:46) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.BSHTryStatement.eval(BSHTryStatement.java:86) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:728) [bsh-2.0b5.jar:2.0b5 2005-06-12 04:50:41]
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.ClientExecuter.execute(ClientExecuter.java:49) [coreserver.jar:?]
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.execute(Loader.java:142) [ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:118) [ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java] Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING TABLE_TYPE IN ('TABLE',null,null,null,null) ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_SC' at line 1
     [java]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
     [java]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
     [java]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
     [java]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:960) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
     [java]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1019) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
     [java]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.executeMetadataQuery(DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.java:62) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
     [java]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.getTables(DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.ddl.tools.persistenceinfo.PersistenceInformation$4.doInConnection(PersistenceInformation.java:296) ~[ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.ddl.tools.persistenceinfo.PersistenceInformation$4.doInConnection(PersistenceInformation.java:1) ~[ybootstrap.jar:?]
     [java]     at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:353) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
     [java]     ... 45 more
     [java] shutting down hybris registry..
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultTaskService] Task engine already stopped.
     [java] INFO  [main] [TenantStartupNotifier] Using default implementation of TenantStartupNotifier for tenant <<junit>>[1689000681]
     [java] INFO  [main] [TenantStartupNotifier] Instantiating de.hybris.platform.core.BlockingTenantStartupNotifier for tenant <<junit>>[1689000681].
     [java] INFO  [main] [TenantStartupNotifier] Using default implementation of TenantStartupNotifier for tenant <<t1>>[-246065169]
     [java] INFO  [main] [TenantStartupNotifier] Instantiating de.hybris.platform.core.BlockingTenantStartupNotifier for tenant <<t1>>[-246065169].
     [java] INFO  [main] [TenantStartupNotifier] Using default implementation of TenantStartupNotifier for tenant <<t2>>[1485094517]
     [java] INFO  [main] [TenantStartupNotifier] Instantiating de.hybris.platform.core.BlockingTenantStartupNotifier for tenant <<t2>>[1485094517].
     [java] INFO  [main] [TenantStartupNotifier] Using default implementation of TenantStartupNotifier for tenant <<foo>>[1562070837]
     [java] INFO  [main] [TenantStartupNotifier] Instantiating de.hybris.platform.core.BlockingTenantStartupNotifier for tenant <<foo>>[1562070837].
     [java] INFO  [AfterSaveEventPublisher-master] [DefaultAfterSaveListenerRegistry] AfterSaveEventPublisher-master has been interrupted - stopping now: sleep interrupted
     [java] INFO  [AfterSaveEventPublisher-master] [DefaultAfterSaveListenerRegistry] AfterSaveEventPublisher-master has been interrupted/terminated but without InterruptedException - stopping now.
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultCacheController] Removed listener from cache controller. Currently registered 1
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultSolrServerService] Stopping Solr servers ...
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultSolrServerService] Stopping Solr server for instance [name: default, hostname: localhost, port: 8983]
     [java] Sending stop command to Solr running on port 8983 ... waiting up to 180 seconds to allow Jetty process 12266 to stop gracefully.
     [java] INFO  [main] [DefaultClusterNodeManagementService] Unregistering assigned cluster node id 0...
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.execute(Loader.java:142)
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:118)
     [java] Caused by: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``try                                {                           de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.AntPerformable p = new de.hybris.a . . . '' : Method Invocation p.doPerform : at Line: 4 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``try                  {                                   de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.AntPerformable p = new de.hybris.a . . . '' : p .doPerform ( )
     [java]
     [java] Target exception: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: ConnectionCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING TABLE_TYPE IN ('TABLE',null,null,null,null) ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_SC' at line 1
     [java]
     [java]     at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:97)
     [java]     at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
     [java]     at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
     [java]     at bsh.BSHBlock.evalBlock(BSHBlock.java:130)
     [java]     at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:80)
     [java]     at bsh.BSHBlock.eval(BSHBlock.java:46)
     [java]     at bsh.BSHTryStatement.eval(BSHTryStatement.java:86)
     [java]     at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645)
     [java]     at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
     [java]     at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:728)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.ClientExecuter.execute(ClientExecuter.java:49)
     [java]     ... 6 more
     [java] shutting down hybris registry..
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING TABLE_TYPE IN ('TABLE',null,null,null,null) ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_SC'

HSSQL works without problems and I'm able to connect to db via mysql workbench.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked Third-Party Compatibility Page  on https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8c71300f866910149b40c88dfc0de431.html

It seems , mysql 8 is not supported .

Comment: In the future can you copy the relevant text into your answer please? it preserves and, in this case as a login in required on that link, allows everyone to see it.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm now able to connect to mysql v5.7 and jdbc v8.0.11